# question about negative infinite

Tags: java

what is equivalent  to negative infinity  in java?−∞

Comment: possible duplicate of [Correct Way to Obtain The Most Negative Double](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389613/correct-way-to-obtain-the-most-negative-double)

Comment: @KennyTM The largest representable number and infinity are not equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the primitive integral types, there are [`Long.MIN_VALUE`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#MIN_VALUE), [`Integer.MIN_VALUE`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MIN_VALUE), and [`Byte.MIN_VALUE`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#MIN_VALUE), .  For double and float, it's a little more complicated.  The smallest "real" values are [`Double.MIN_VALUE`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MIN_VALUE) and [`Float.MIN_VALUE`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#MIN_VALUE), respectively.  However, there are also [`Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#NEGATIVE_INFINITY) and [`Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#NEGATIVE_INFINITY).

Comment: No, `Double.MIN_NORMAL` is the smallest normal value. There are even smaller "subnormal values", `Double.MIN_VALUE`.

Answer (score 6):

[Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#NEGATIVE_INFINITY) and [Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#NEGATIVE_INFINITY).

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY ?