# Bug sorting negative numbers in an array (double)

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, negative-number

Here we are, facing an odd issue with a sorting of two arrays: The numbers within them are key to show off the top and bottom, max and min, of these array's in order to draw them in a line.

Here are the two arrays:

```
double[] hor = {5.938, 5.989, 6.047, 6.105, 6.159, 6.211, 6.260, 6.314, 6.351};
double[] vert = {-6.589,-6.348, -5.991, -5.691,- 5.491, -5.203, -4.989,- 4.805, -4.650};
```

aAnd the function:

```
public void escala(double[] hor, double[] vert) {

    double minX = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    double maxX = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    for (double x : hor) {
        if (x < minX)
            minX  = x;
        if (x > maxX)
            maxX  = x;

    }
    double minY = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    double maxY = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    for (double y : vert) {
        if (y < minY)
            minY  = y;
        if (y > maxY)
            maxY  = y;
    }

    double margin=0.00;
    final double actualMaxY = maxY+margin*(maxY-minY);
    final double actualMinY = minY-margin*(maxY-minY);
    final double actualMaxX = maxX+margin*(maxX-minX);
    final double actualMinX = minX-margin*(maxX-minX);

    System.err.println("actualMinY==" + actualMinY);
    System.err.println("actualMaxY==" + actualMaxY);

    cgraf.setLimits(actualMinX, actualMaxX, actualMinY, actualMaxY, (maxX-minX)/5, (maxY-minY)/10);
    ccur.setLimits(actualMinX, actualMaxX, actualMinY, actualMaxY, (maxX-minX)/5, (maxY-minY)/10);

}
```

And the headache of the result is this:

- Max value = 0.000  (Of course, 4.9E-324)
- Min Value = -6.589

It works properly for arrays with positive numbers. But with this negative numbers array, it crashes. Any idea on how to change the code to make it able to work?

The expected result is:

- Max value = -4.650
- Min Value = -6.589

This function is needed to send values to a graphics class in the applet.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Look in the Math class for helper methods

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that

```
double maxY = Double.MIN_VALUE;
```

is near `0`, in fact it is `4.9E-324` which is equivalent to `4.9 * Math.pow(10, -324)`. That's why the sorting is not working. You could try

```
double maxY = -Double.MAX_VALUE;
```

instead.

**`Double.MIN_VALUE`:** A constant holding the smallest positive nonzero value of type double, 2^(-1074).

**Note:** You may want to change `maxX` too.

**Edit:** You may also find interesting this: `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`.

Comment: Beaten by a few seconds. See also [Double.MIN_VALUE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MIN_VALUE) and ["Correct Way to Obtain The Most Negative Double"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389613/correct-way-to-obtain-the-most-negative-double). IMO the JDK should have named it something else.

Comment: See also [`Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#NEGATIVE_INFINITY)